# Stop a portion of Javascript function from auto firing

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to stop the script and wait for user input before continuing it?
Here is the portion that I need to stop:

```
  var nName = document.getElementById("b1");
  nName.innerHTML = "Continue";
  document.getElementById("b1").onclick = newName();
```

So "b1" is a HTML button, I want to stop it after

```
nName.innerHTML = "Continue";
```

and wait for user click on the button before firing

```
document.getElementById("b1").onclick = newName();
```

using return completely stop the script. Is there any other possible way to do this?

Comment: Nope. JS is not CPP, its all about async stuff and callbacks. I'd just add return instead of the last statement. And put the last line into the button click callback.

Comment: In order to listen the user's click event you need `document.getElementById("b1").onclick` but you need to create it after user's click? My brain got hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to stop the script. You cannot.

Pass references to the functions (no paranthesis on the function names) like so:

```
document.getElementById("b1").onclick = newName;
```

Example:

```js
function firstClick(){
  document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML = "Continue"
  // override the first click listener. "firstClick" will no longer be called.
  document.getElementById('b1').onclick = newName;
}
function newName(){
  document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML = "Good Job!"
}

// listen for first click
document.getElementById('b1').onclick = firstClick
```

```html
<button id=b1>Click Me!</button>
```

In order to fully understand what is going on, I do must refer you do Google and Documentation, and most of all - Experimentation.

But in short, in not technical terms.

`onclick` does nothing on its own. It needs to be told what it does. The browser will do what you tell it to. There can only be 1 function assigned to it. So if you do `onclick=a; onclick=b; onclick=c`, only `c` will be called.

If you assign the function name with paranthesis `onclick = newName()`, what you are doing is you are running the newName() and assigning its return to the onclick. So in this case - nothing. If you do `onclick=newName` the borwser will automatgically add the paranthesis.

---

You could even create a 'triaging' function to decide what the next steps are:

```js
function triage(){
  var el = document.getElementById('b1');
  if (el.innerHTML == "Continue"){
    el.innerHTML = 'Good Job!';
  }else{
    el.innerHTML = 'Continue';
  }
}

// listen for first click
document.getElementById('b1').onclick = triage
```

```html
<button id=b1>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I think I missed the explanation there. What I want to do is, when I click the button for the first time, it run the first script, rename the button and stop there, wait for user to click the button again and execute the newName() script.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for, thanks alot! But for clarity, would you mind to explain the logic behind the code? I'm still learning JS and have a lot to learn.